# Converting to HH:MM:SS

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL server job that goes out and imports a text file.  one line of this job is as follows:

```
SUBSTRING(Line, 61, 5) AS Col06,
```

This is getting a 5 digit number (the duration of a call) and placing it into a nvarchar(50) field.  I would like to convert this into `HH:MM:SS`.

Can you assist?  I am quite new to this so explain as if I was stupid.

Comment: Well duration...in WHICH FORMAT? Hours with fractions? Seconds? Ticks?

Comment: @silentbob: Why nvarchar(50)? Why not cast the result of Royi's suggestion to TIME(0) and store it in a much smaller (3 bytes per row vs the 18 bytes for nvarchar) and more appropriate field? This would also be cheaper to index for searching and to do time math calculations.

Answer (score 1):

YOu can try this:-

where 1000 is the number of seconds

```
  SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(8),DATEADD(second,1000,0),108)
```

Example :

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(8),DATEADD(second,CAST (SUBSTRING('the call was 10000 seconds', 14, 5) AS INT),0),108)
```

Comment: @DaveRlz what r u talking about ? 108 is the correct format and NOT 114

Comment: Well, just to be clear I haven't downvoted you, but your answer is identical to @Rahul (below) and even includes the same typo and numbers. Someone is copying someone...perhaps you should have added a comment instead.

Comment: @RoyiNamir - a minute ago, your question was identical to Rahul's post, and had 114 as the conversion type.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables nevermind. my solution is working. and it was 1 minute before others , and look at their edits to see they changed from 114 to 108. ( and ofcourse Ive edited his answer as a nistake , maybe I had his answer in clipboard , cause i wanted to test it in sql . and by mistake i pasted it. any way - the pasted edit ( 114) is wrong. it should be 108